# How to exclude a form file field on $this->save()?

Tags: php, cakephp

When a user is created he upload a file.

I want to edit this user, but, when he save and not select any file, in other words, he wants to keep the original, I get this error:

```
SQL Query: UPDATE `societario`.`attorneys` SET `nome` = 'teste', `empresa` = 'Sotreq', `filial` = 'Matriz', `unidade` = 'Energia', `alcada` = 'Até 50.000', `validade` = '', `arquivo` = Array WHERE `societario`.`attorneys`.`id` = '42'
```

If the user dont select any file, i want that save dont get the `$this->Attorney->data['Attorney']['arquivo']`

My edit.php

```
function edit($id = null) {



    $this->Attorney->id = $id;
    $this->set('poderes',$this->Attorney->Power->find('list', array('fields' => 'resumo')));

         if ($this->request->is('get')) {
            $this->request->data = $this->Attorney->read();
        } else {

            if ($this->Attorney->save($this->request->data)) {

            $targetFolder = 'societario/app/webroot/uploads/'; // Relative to the root
            $tempFile = $this->request->data['Attorney']['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
            $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
            $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $this->request->data['Attorney']['arquivo']['name'];;
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
            $this->Attorney->updateAll(
             array('arquivo' => "'".$this->request->data['Attorney']['arquivo']['name'] ."'"),
            array('id' => $id));    

            $this->Session->setFlash('Usuário editado com sucesso!', 'default', array('class' => 'flash_sucess'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'usuarios'));
    }
}

}
```

If I try to upload a file isn't working either. The same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to exclude that field, just unset that key in the array, before you call save:

```
unset($this->Attorney->data['Attorney']['arquivo']);
```

Second, for file uploads, you should consider using a plugin to help you out - it will save you a world of pain! I use https://github.com/josegonzalez/upload

Answer (score 0):

Look at:

```
`arquivo` = Array
```

Raw MySQL queries won't handle an Array. You need to process the Array into a data type MySQL will understand.

Comment: yes, I know... I want to exclude that field if no file is selected.

Comment: Ah, ok. @joshua.paling has got what you need. You'll just need to place that into a conditional when there is no file upload.

`if(!isset($this->request->data['Attorney']['arquivo']['tmp_name'])) {...`